# Git: difference between cloning from url.git vs url/.git

Tags: git, github

I've always cloned my repositories with the following URL:

```
https://github.com/joaquinlpereyra/twitterImgBot.git
```

But I have found out that you can also clone repos by directing clone to the .git folder, like this:

```
$ git clone http://examplerepo.com/.git/
```

This doesn't work on github, though, but I know from experience that this works on at least one HTTP non-Github git repository, while trying to do the following:

```
$ git clone http.//examplerepo.com
```

doesn't work at all.

Anyone has information on this .git vs /.git difference? I've tried searching but I haven't seen cloning the /.git folder anywhere except on the last example of the [git reference](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone), which gives the following example:

```
$ git clone --bare -l /home/proj/.git /pub/scm/proj.git
```

But no information on why it is cloning the .git folder instead of /home/proj directly is left out.

I'd appreciate any information or directive! Thanks.

Comment: See if `git clone -v` discloses anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git supports a few different protocols. Which one is used depends on several factors, such as whether git is running on the remote end (smart vs. dumb), or if it's possible to list directory contents (e.g. local file or FTP or WebDAV vs. HTTP in the general case).

If you're just using a plain HTTP server, then git can fetch from it using dumb HTTP transport as long as [git-update-server-info](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/git-update-server-info.txt) has been run to help it out (see [gitrepository-layout](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/gitrepository-layout.txt)). You have to specifically include `/.git/` in the URL path.

GitHub of course is using the smart HTTP transport, and this is not really related to the `.git/` at the end being optional. (GitHub [doesn't support dumb http transport](https://github.com/blog/809-git-dumb-http-transport-to-be-turned-off-in-90-days).)

The smart HTTP protocol can compute packfiles on the fly and can also be pushed to. See [http-protocol](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/http-protocol.txt).

For cloning a local path, the `/.git/` on the end being optional makes sense because git can traverse the local filesystem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

No differences in cloned objects 
Both URLs are cloning the same content

Only [remote "origin"] section inside .git/config is set bit different but this is normal:

```
[remote "origin"]
     url = ssh://localhost:29418/test/.git/
```

VS

```
[remote "origin"]
     url = ssh://localhost:29418/test.git
```

When you clone it without .git

```
[remote "origin"]
     url = ssh://localhost:29418/test
```

All three are doing the same thing

Comment: I suspected the same, but then why one of the options works on a repository and the other does not?

Comment: I assume this is some server side restriction (apache, nginx etc.) related to path traversing or something else and has nothing to do with git internals.